Will we ever be able to completely understand nature precisely?
What I mean is that we have certain physical laws for simple systems like 2 point masses, that work for every possible configuration(by the principle of superposition), there are problems like the 3 body problem which (in present time) cannot be totally solved. This prompted me to think, the objective of physics is to explain(and predict) the natural phenomenon around us. Given that there exist problems which cannot be exactly solved, I am confused with what the true objective of physics is. Is it to explain stuff in a simplified manner or precisely find out the cause and predict the future?

"completly"? maybe is meaningless. "precisely"? current scientific knowledge: physics, biology, achieved impressive levels of precision. See e.g. Mars Exploration Rover it sound quite precise...

Remember that the only real referent of the phrase "objective of physics" is the list of possible objectives of a particular person who is doing physics - i.e., what it is to do physics at all, and what incentives and constraints act on the human beings who do it. Anthropomorphizing collectives makes you prone to errors.

The 3-body problem has been "exactly solved" by Sundman in 1912 in the same sense as the simple pendulum, say, he gave a convergent power series for the general solution. The problem is that it converges too slowly to be useful for predictions, and it makes qualitative features of the solution too opaque to be useful for explanations. Predictions and explanations are a large part of physics' "true objective", but "exactly solving" is neither necessary nor sufficient for it.

In the words of kurtzgesagt, the purpose of science is to constantly find out that things work in ways we never expected, until we know exactly how the universe works. I liked that

"...what the true objective of physics is." You'll likely get as many answers as there are people. It's not like there is a Physics Czar who decides such absolutes. It's probably not helpful to think is such black and white terms. Just because we (probably) can never know everything, doesn't mean there isn't joy in and practical uses for learning what we can.

Regarding "the objective of physics" << presumably, every person who chooses physics as their professional field does it for personal reasons, which might differ from one individual to another; and governments and companies who fund physics labs do it for economical reasons which might differ, too.

@Conifold Plus, numerical approaches to the problem are accurate enough and fast enough that we don't need to use the analytical solution. The approximations are good enough for most if not all practical purposes.

We have solved the 3-body problem. We have even solved the n-body problem. The issue is having enough computing power, to make those solutions practical.

There are different kinds of obstructions to "perfect" knowledge/exact solvability, and it's important to disambiguate them. To do so, and to probe what exactly "exactly solvable" ought to mean, let's start with pure mathematics so we can hold off on things like the problem of induction.

√2 and problematizing "exact"

We know exactly what √2 is. It's the length of the unit square's diagonal. It's the unique positive number whose square is 2. We can work with it algebraically, and we can approximate it as a rational however well we want, provided we have enough time and space for the calculation.
So
x² = 2
is exactly solvable. The solution is x=√2 exactly
But
(a/b)² = 2 where a, b are integers
is not exactly solvable. This is not to say it's not solved yet, nor that solution cannot be known. There is no solution because what we're asking for doesn't make sense. It's like
1 = 0,
also unsolvable.
So the phrase "exact solution" is not nuanced enough. Exact in what sense? Solved in what sense? These nuances are related to the ontology of mathematical objects—what is √2? where does it live? how do we get at it? Is it the same kind of existence as 1?
If you demand a rational number, then, no, x²=2 has no exact solution. But if you merely want a finite description, then, yes there's an exact solution. You can go further: you can approximate √2 as precisely as you wish using an algorithm, but more precision costs more work.

The 3-body problem, purely mathematically

The situation is analogous for the 3 body problem. x² = 2 has a solution. x² = 2 has no rational solution. The three body problem has a solution. It has no closed form solution.
Can we solve the 3-body problem exactly? What are your standards of exact-ness? Given precisely-enough known initial conditions, we can approximate the solution arbitrarily well for an arbitrarily large but finite length of time. We also know, like √2, the solution is uniquely determined from the initial conditions. In these senses, an exact solution exists.
The 3-body problem is chaotic. Chaotic is not unpredictable. It is more subtle. Chaotic means uncertainty in the initial conditions compounds over time. If you know the exact initial conditions, you get an exact trajectory. In the other direction, if you want to predict what will happen far into the future to your desired precision, there is a corresponding level of accuracy of the initial conditions that will let you do that.

Physicality

Space isn't (x,y,z) coordinates of real numbers. Planets aren't points. There are limits to our ability to measure initial conditions. Some of these are physical and some are social/practical. For example, you can only go so precise in measuring initial conditions before quantum effects become relevant. Every mathematical model has a domain of applicability. By studying the model, we can understand reality. Even properties that occur in the model outside the domain of applicability can still give us clues about "actual" reality (ignoring hard solipsism, etc etc).

Information overload

Even if you want to study a gas in a 1x1x1 cube, to exactly solve the equations of motion, you need to know the initial conditions of every molecule in that cube. This is impossible to measure. To measure a molecule, you need to interact with it, changing its trajectory. But even if you could know this, what do you do with it? Avogadro's number is giant: there's on the order of 10²³ molecules in this cube. What could possibly store the result of 10²³ measurements?
Similarly, there's probably an upper-bound on the amount of information a brain can hold. Nature may even have an upper bound on the possible information density altogether, and the observable universe is much larger than the human brain.

Now what?

In short, the goal of physics is to know more than we did yesterday. What, specifically, will depend on the physicist. But we can see some general trends
Physics is about the interface of two kinds of knowledge: mathematical, deductive knowledge; and empirical, experimental knowledge. You idealize physical properties into a mathematical model, extract predictions, and then compare with experiment. Because of the tension between inductive and deductive knowledge, this can be philosophically interesting.
We can find basic laws that were never falsified after extensive experimentation, like the speed of light is constant. Then, we can deduce profound consequences mathematically: for example, energy-mass equivalence. Even prior to experimental verification of energy-mass equivalence, we can still put confidence in it because of the combined effect of the confidence in our basic laws/assumptions and the confidence in our deductions.
These inferences are surprisingly powerful. For example, combining Heisenberg's uncertainty principle with special relativity suggests anti-particles exist. This is roughly how Dirac predicted the positron. In words, the Heisenberg uncertainty principle combined with relativity tells us that, on the quantum scale, the speed of light is a statistical limit, ie, blurry. But relativity also tells us if something were to move faster than the speed of light, to some observer, it would appear to go backwards in time. So we should expect to see a particle that behaves like what you'd expect if an electron were to go backwards through time, a positron.
Note, this does not break causality because there is no way for information to travel faster than the speed of light.
Edit:

Aesthetics and the human mind

Physicists (and mathematicians) often speak about aesthetics, especially elegance. Sometimes it sounds like there's an underlying assumption that the more we learn about nature the more beautiful the laws that describe it will become. I'm sure some people literally believe that, but I don't think that's what is really going on. To understand aesthetics as a goal of physics, we have to ask what makes something elegant to a physicist.
But first, some observations about the human condition. Compared to the universe, humans are small, short-lived, and stupid. We can only hold a few ideas in mind at once. Even relatively simple logical deductions confuse us.
Much of the work of understanding physics and mathematics, therefore, is organizing and reorganizing knowledge into a form that the human brain can  unerstand effectively. The first time a new result is proved, the proof is probably two dozen pages. By the time it makes it into a textbook, though, the proof has been whittled down to one or two paragraphs. Maxwell's equations were originally 20 equations. The sheer number of equations was a difficulty. Heavyside reorganized them using vector calculus, resulting in four equations, much more manageable. The content is the same, but Heavyside's reorganization is more compatible with the human mind. Therefore, humans find it more elegant.
Explanatory power is also elegant, particularly when it brings insight.
In this sense, special relativity is elegant. Not only does special relativity solve the moving magnet and conductor proble, but, in doing so, tells us where Faraday's induction comes from. Induction is required by Lorentz invariance: magnetic fields only act on moving charges, but motion is relative; therefore, magnetism can't stand alone.
The search for elegance is really the search for deeper human understanding. Them more we learn about nature, the harder our knowledge becomes for humans to understand, the more we're forced to elegance to manage.

"But (a/b)² = 2 where a, b are integers is not exactly solvable." - We might argue that that's a matter of careless phrasing of the question. The question, "What is the set of integer pairs (a,b) for which (a/b)² = 2?" does have a definite answer: the empty set.

Definitely. "No exact solution" is an exact solution.
This stresses the difference between exact and useful answers. Useful depends on context. It's often better to have an inexact but concrete useful answer, eg √2 ≈ 1.41. Because physicists work with models and measurements, there is already some limit to the precision, so rounding √2 won't matter.
For algebra, irrationality of √2 is important. It means x²-2 is irreducible. This thinking says why Doubling the cube is impossible.

You say/ask:

I am confused with what the true objective of physics is. Is it to explain stuff in a simplified manner or precisely find out the cause and predict the future?

The goal of physics, and science, for most scientists, is to develop theories that are consistent with observations and that make accurate predictions about future events. See generally, Eric Christian Barnes, "Predictivism" in Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy and Karl Popper, The Logic of Scientific Discovery.
Some go further to posit scientific realism, but this is neither universal nor necessary to the practical utility of physics or science. See Anjan Chakravartty, "Scientific Realism" in Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy.

Your title question and the final question in your post are different.

The objective of physics is to find out the laws of inanimate nature.
In particular to reduce different laws to a common more fundamental
law.
IMO we will never have a complete understanding of nature: New
observations and the discovery of new phenomena open up new domains
of resarch which before were unknown or out of scope.


I'm unfamiliar with philosophy jargon, so I am wondering what "inanimate nature" means here. As a physicist, I'd argue we're plenty concerned with animate nature too, at least as far as I understand the words.

@d_b I mean nature without living beings, the latter being the subject of biology. How does one correctly say in English?

Your English is fine. Physicalism is broader than physics was the counterpoint.  I'd offer the OP my criticism that laws are constructed; it is regularities that are discovered, to keep the map and the territory in perspective.

Marshall McLuhan famously said "the map is not the territory."  Similarly, "laws" or "theories" in science are models describing how reality seems to work.  They are not the actual reality.
For a time, the Newtonian model was the best one for certain things.  Then Einstein came up with a model that was more accurate than Newton's.  Maybe someday we'll come up with an even better model.  But we'll never know whether the latest and greatest model is the best one possible.  But even if it is the best one possible, it will still be only a model, not the reality.

Our brains are products of Nature.
If the human brain was simple enough that we could perfectly understand them, then WE would be too simple to possibly achieve that level of cognition.
Almost necessarily, an organism cannot fully comprehend the brain with which they do their comprehension.
Like how emulating a computer system generally requires a much more powerful computer system.
If we are unable to "fully understand our own brains" then we will never be able to "fully understand nature".
It is still very interesting TO our brains to try and understand as much as we can about our brains, even if we can never know it all.

The study of physics has different objectives, depending on the practicioner.
Many are mostly interested in practical results. For these scientists, we only need to understand nature precisely enough to make or do useful things. For example, Newton's laws of motion and gravity are generally good enough to calculate spaceship trajectories -- they don't go fast enough for the increased accuracy in Einstein's theory of relativity to make a significant difference.
But there are also theoretical physicists who do this mostly to satisfy curiosity. There's probably little practical benefit to cosmology; the conditions of the universe in the moments after the big bang will not be replicated (or if they are, we couldn't be there to experience it).
There's good reason to believe that there can never be a complete answer to the "why?" questions. Every time we explain something more precisely, it just raises new questions. After we discovered atoms we had to understand what its constituents are. Once we figured out that they're made of protons, neutrons, and electrons we needed to figure out what they're made of. Now we know that protons and neutrons are made of quarks, but we want to know what they're made of; this is the subject of current research (ideas like string theory come from this).
I like to analogize this to the progression of questions that arise when a child asks a parent "why is the sky blue?". The only way this stops is when the parent puts a stop to it with something like "just because."
The Principle of Sufficient Reason says there's an explanation for everything and anything. This implies an infinite regress of explanations for physical processes, or the PSR is false.

The PSR brings us to Kant's 3rd antimomy - e.g. "Now this again presupposes, in conformity with the law of nature, a previous condition and its causality, and this another anterior to the former, and so on. If, then, everything happens solely in accordance with the laws of nature, there cannot be any real first beginning of things, but only a subaltern or comparative beginning. There cannot, therefore, be a completeness of series on the side of the causes which originate the one from the other. . . ." So it's still a mystery.

You ask:

Will we ever be able to completely understand nature precisely?

No. Not everything is knowable and provable. Take Heisenberg's uncertainty principle. From the article:

It states that there is a limit to the precision with which certain pairs of physical properties, such as position and momentum, can be simultaneously known. In other words, the more accurately one property is measured, the less accurately the other property can be known.

That means even if we could build a computer big enough to store information on every particle we came across (assuming that particles exist and that had an endless supply of matter and energy that wasn't part of the physical universe, whatever that would mean), we still do not have the ability to construct certain types of of information simultaneously.
You also ask:

Given that there exist problems which cannot be exactly solved, I am confused with what the true objective of physics is.

The point is to figure out as much as we can. You don't have to have 'perfect' information to have useful information. If we can just build a better heat pump... computer... plane... etc.
